# How to set the keymap for keyboards that are plugged in later?

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb, input

I have configured my keyboard layout by adding a call to `setxkbmap` to my `.xinitrc`. This works for my laptop's internal keyboard and for any external keyboard that is plugged in when the X server starts. If I plug in an external keyboard later, it uses the default US keymap.

How can I make sure that any keyboard that I plug in has my preferred layout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Gilles commented on Dominik R's answer yesterday, the udev approach only works for the root user and doesn't work well as a general, unprivileged solution. I'd suggest considering inputplug(1) by Andrew Shadura available in Debian as the package inputplug as well as at the [project site](https://github.com/andrewshadura/inputplug).

inputplug(1) is a rather straightforward as a XINPUT event loop listener which will invoke a script with decoded event parameters as arguments. Since you're using .xinitrc, I imagine you're using a modest window manager / environment and a background listener of this sort should be pretty straightforward for you.

Another possibility is using udev in a less traditional way by writing a script parsing the output from "udevadm monitor" and invoking setxkbmap upon recognizing a matching device being connnected.

Good Luck!

Comment: I am using a modest input manager but I am a beginner at that so some example calls to inputplug would be much appreciated.

Comment: Added a complete example as an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

`inputplug`, suggested by etherfish five years ago, is an excellent answer, but the answer was missing a complete example. So here is what I use in my `.xinitrc` to run `setxkbmap` exactly once in the beginning, and another time every time a new keyboard is plugged in:

```bsh
{ echo "XIDeviceEnabled XISlaveKeyboard"; inputplug -d -c /bin/echo; } |
while read event
do
        case $event in
        XIDeviceEnabled*XISlaveKeyboard*)
                setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll us,il ,lyx
                setxkbmap -option caps:none
                ;;
        esac
done &
```

The `inputplug -d -c /bin/echo` echos a message like

```
XIDeviceEnabled 11 XISlaveKeyboard Logitech K270
```

every time a keyboard is plugged in, and the `while` loop finds such messages and causes the relevant `setxkbmap` commands to run (in my example, I set a Hebrew keyboard mapping, and remove the Caps Lock feature which I hate). The extra `echo "XIDeviceEnabled XISlaveKeyboard"` in the beginning causes the loop to also find a "new keyboard" exactly once in the beginning. `inputplug` also has a "-0" option to print existing keyboards on startup, but this will usually print multiple keyboards and cause the `setxkbmap` to be needlessly run multiple times on startup.

Comment: Thank you for adding extra detail and an example!

Comment: Author here. You can also directly call your script with `-c`, this is actually how it’s intended to be used — just put the `case`/`esac` into a separate script and run inputplug as a dæmon.

Comment: Yes, indeed it's also possible to pass a separate handler script to inputplug. However, since anyway I need to write code to **run** inputplug - in my .xinitrc - I wanted all the related code to be in one place, and not have to create a separate handler script somewhere else.

Comment: That seems like a fairly common use case, it may be worth having `-c` take `-` as argument, and `inputplug` would read the script on the standard input.  It feels quite natural to then write `inputplug -c - << EOF` followed by the script.