# linux: detect if external keyboard is plugged to laptop

Tags: linux, virtualbox, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have an OSX laptop with a running Ubuntu Virtualbox and I either interact with it with the laptop keyboard or with an external USB keyboard that I plug in when in the office.

Is there a script I could run to detect if the external keyboard is plugged so that the keymap in Ubuntu Virtualbox changes accordingly?

I currently manually run either 'mac' or 'key' which executes this command:

```
setxkbmap -layout gb
```

or

```
xmodmap .Xmodmap
```

I would like to do the same automatically when the keyboard is plugged or unplugged. Any ideas?

Comment: use a `udev`-rule. You can make it run a specific script once a specific device is plugged in or out.

Comment: Can the script be triggered when it's plugged? What would be the best way?

Comment: See also [How to set the keymap for keyboards that are plugged in later?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253489/how-to-set-the-keymap-for-keyboards-that-are-plugged-in-later) which provides a way to do this without being root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `udev`-rule for this. In my example I am using a USB dongle for my wireless mouse, you will have to adjust accordingly:

**1. Getting the identifiers**

In order to make a unique rule for the device, we need to identify it properly. Use the output of `udevadm` for this ( your USB keyboard should show in `/dev/usb/<device>`. Plug it in and out to see if this device (dis)appears ). The vendor and device IDs should be unique enough, but the more matches, the better.

```
udeadm info -a -n /dev/usb/hiddev0 | grep 'idVendor\|idProduct'
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0e8f"
ATTRS{idProduct}=="00a4"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
ATTRS{idProduct}=="0001"
```

Note the two values that match the output from `lsusb` at ID (to know which device this is, either test the difference of `lsubs` with and without the keyboard, or see if you can match the names in the output)

```
lsusb
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 0e8f:00a4 GreenAsia Inc.
```

So we will use `0e8f` and `00a4` for vendor and product ID, respectively.

**2. Creating a rule**

The rule itself is just a listing of what to do. Save it in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` as e.g. `keyboard.rules` (note that the `.rules` suffix is obligatory). The file will match (`==`) a few attributes, the action, and run our script:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0e8f", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00a4", RUN+="/full/path/to/script.sh"
```

You might run into problems for the `ACTION=="remove"` part, have a read of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65363/udev-not-running-remove-events). The problem being some of the attributes being deleted upon removal, and thus `udev` cannot match them anymore for your removal rule.

In my case I used `udeadm monitor --environemnt` and unplugged the devive. I selected

```
ID_MODEL_ID=00a4
```

and used this as the only requirement (you might need to do a bit of trial and error for good matches here, however a single match is rather save for your case of changing keymaps only). Note that the removal rule needs `ENV` instead of `ATTRS` (AFAIK `ENV` works for the plugin rule, too, but `ATTRS` fails for removal)

```
ACTION=="remove", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="00a4", RUN+="/path/to/removal_script.sh"
```

The add and remove rules can be one file with one line for each action.

**3. The script**

The script will ALWAYS be run by `root`, so make sure that a) it is writeable by `root` only (for security reasons) b) if your command needs to be executed by a user, use `sudo -u user1 command` in the script. It should be executable of course.
If you are trying to directly execute a command (i.e. without using a script) use the absolute path of said command.

Good luck.