# How do I fix exit code 1 for a systemd service running inputplug?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, xkb, setxkbmap

I want to set up a `systemd` service to set my custom keymap when my bluetooth keyboard is plugged. I am using `inputplug`, as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253489/how-to-set-the-keymap-for-keyboards-that-are-plugged-in-later).

Since I need to have an executable command containing no spaces (see [here](https://github.com/andrewshadura/inputplug), Option `-c`), I wrote a wrapper script that is executable:

`/home/maddin/.local/bin/setmykeymap`:

```
#!/bin/sh

setxkbmap us-de
```

Now if I execute `inputplug` in a terminal, everything works as expected, regardless of whether I use `sudo` or not.

```
$ [sudo] /usr/bin/inputplug -c /home/maddin/.local/bin/setmykeymap
Linked without daemon(), running in foreground.
```

It does set my keyboard layout upon connecting to my keyboard. The message is the same, no matter if I use `-d` or not. I guess the reason for that is that I am running it in a terminal and that is detected somehow.

So far, so good.

Now I have set up a `systemd` service, following [this guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/687970/how-to-run-a-linux-program-at-startup-with-systemd/). I looks like this:
`/etc/systemd/system/inputplug-keymap-daemon.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Sets xkbmap to us-de anytime a device is plugged or unplugged

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/inputplug -c /home/maddin/.local/bin/setmykeymap
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
KillMode=mixed

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After enabling the service and restarting, I get:

```
$ sudo systemctl status inputplug-keymap-daemon.service                                                                                                                              
● inputplug-keymap-daemon.service - Sets xkbmap to us-de anytime a device is plugged or unplugged
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/inputplug-keymap-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-01-19 13:26:48 CET; 1s ago
    Process: 74130 ExecStart=/usr/bin/inputplug -c /home/maddin/.local/bin/setmykeymap (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 74130 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Which `Wants`, `After`, `WantedBy` etc. would you set for such a service?

Comment: Remove the double-quotes from the `ExecStart=` line.

Comment: Thanks! I did that, now I get a different Error: `Process: 3219 ExecStart=/usr/bin/inputplug -c /home/maddin/.local/bin/setmykeymap (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comments, you've solved the syntax issue which caused the `203`.  Now you have error-code `1`.  This comes from the application itself.

Monitor `journalctl -u inputplug-keymap-daemon.service` to see if the application is writing anything to stdout or stderr.  Adding -v to the command-line arguments may help get more info.

When I look at the [man page](http://manpages.org/inputplug), it's clear that this application uses the `DISPLAY` environment variable.  This is not something that is normally available to system daemons and is my guess for why this is failing.

As soon as we deal with services which need access to the `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY`, we are usually working in the user-realm.  It means this is something that isn't needed for the system itself to operate, it's something specific to the user and their graphical session.  In this situation we use the `--user` bus of systemd.  The `--user` bus will give your service access to your environment including the `DISPLAY`.

To make this work:

```
sudo systemctl disable inputplug-keymap-daemon.service
cp /etc/systemd/system/inputplug-keymap-daemon.service ~/.config/systemd/user/
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/inputplug-keymap-daemon.service
systemctl --user start inputplug-keymap-daemon.service
```

Note the lack of `sudo` in the last line.  Check it with `systemctl --user status ...` and `journalctl --user -u inputplug-keymap-daemon.service`

If it works, then change your `[Install]` section before enabling the service:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Now you can `systemctl --user enable inputplug-keymap-daemon.service`

Comment: Don't forget the `systemctl --user daemon-reload` after adding/changing user unit files.

Comment: your suspitions were right, `journalctl` said `X Input not available`. I did everything, starting the service works. However, when I `systemctl --user enable default.target`, I get `The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl. [...]`. I probably could just enable the service directly instead of via `default.target`, but I guess there is a method to keeping it clean like this. How do I fix this?

Comment: I found out that `default.target` is already enabled, so I assume in the last line you meant `systemctl --user enable inputplug-keymap-daemon.service`. Like this, it works like a charm! :)

Comment: Yep, you're right.  That was a mistake on my part.  Thanks for the edit.